# Todas as entidades do modelo conceitual precisam estar relacionadas?

Tags: modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estava desenvolvendo um modelo conceitual para um banco de dados de acordo com os requisitos da atividade, porém me surgiu a dúvida do título pois meu modelo acabou ficando de acordo com o da imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que não seja necessário todas as entidades estarem relacionadas, imagine um sistema de veterinários onde o usuário do sistema cadastra os dados do PET e do dono o PET, neste caso a entidade `PET`x tem que está relacionada a `CLIENTE` que seria o dono do PET, mas a entidade `USERS`, correspondente aos usuários que utilizam o sistema não precisa está relacionada a nenhuma das outras entidades, a menos que no Modelo de Negócios, seja necessário saber quem atendeu o CLIENTE 'x', por exemplo.

Comment: Nem todas as entidades precisam obrigatoriamente estar relacionadas contudo os relacionamentos é que são a riqueza de seu modelo de dados. Questione o porquê da existência de uma entidade sem relacionamentos em seu modelo.